# How can I prevent Cufon from being inherited in submenus?

Tags: javascript, css, joomla, cufon

I am trying to have cufon render fonts in the top level of a UL/LI menu structure.  How can I prevent cufon from rendering fonts or inheriting the style in the submenus.

I have added a class to the top menu level only, 'top', and a separate class for all submenus, 'sub'.

I would really like to have cufon disabled for the submenus, but if that can't be done, then loading another font and restyling would be acceptable also.  I have tried both methods, but the inheritance is very persistent.

Here's the cufon code:

```
Cufon.replace("li.top:not(li.top>ul>li.sub)", { fontFamily: "SerpentineDBol", 
                        //hover: true, 
                        hover: {
                          textShadow: '1px 1px #febf00',
                          color: '-linear-gradient(black, lightgray)'
                        },
hoverables: { li: true }, textShadow: "1px 1px white", color: "-linear-gradient(black, lightgray)" });
Cufon.replace("li.top>ul>li.sub", {fontFamily: "Arial Black" });
```

and the menu format here:

```
<nav class="isi-nav clearfix">
    <div class="isi-nav-inner">
       <ul class="isi-hmenu" id="topmatt">
          <li class="item-464 active top">
             <a class=" active" href="/j25/">Home</a>
           </li>
           <li class="item-444 deeper parent top">
             <a href="/j25/index.php/sample-sites">Sample Sites</a>
             <ul>
               <li class="item-545 sub">
                 <a href="/j25/index.php/sample-sites-2/banner-module">Banner Module</a>
               </li>
               <li class="item-546 sub">
                 <a href="/j25/index.php/sample-sites-2/archive-module">Archive Module</a>
               </li>
              </ul>
             </li>
             <li class="item-476 top">
                <a href="/j25/index.php/captcha">Captcha</a>
             </li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </nav>
```

In the cufon code, I have tried defining a different font style for the 'sub' class, but it is being over ridden by the upper level 'top' style.  Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out what I had to do to prevent the sub level UL to not be set through cufon.  I did not need to use the complicated

li.top:not(li.top>ul>li.sub) .

I just needed to designate the .top class by itself and then add

ignore: { ul: true },

to the cufon settings and it disregarded the rest of the menu items.